# Cassandra reaper - should I repair also reapers database?

Tags: cassandra

So I have installed cassandra-reaper, and I have setup schedules for every Wednesday to repair my projects db. I'm just wondering if there is any need to schedule also a repair for the cassandra-reapers database, which was created?

Comment: I guess, yes. At least this is what I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, No because Reaper is just UI to schedule and manage Cassandra cluster.
It improves the existing nodetool repair process by

Splitting repair jobs into smaller tunable segments.
Handling back-pressure through monitoring running repairs and pending compaction.
Adding ability to pause or cancel repairs and track progress precisely.
Reaper ships with a REST API, a command line tool and a web UI.